# Using Jboss Portal, How do I retrieve page properties in a jsp?

Tags: jsp, properties, jboss-portal

Using **Jboss portal**, how do I retrieve the page properties in a jsp?

I've declared my page like that in `*-object.xml file`:

```
<page>
  <page-name>MyPage</page-name>
  <properties>
    <property>
      <name>layout.id</name>
      <value>generic</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hidePanel</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
</page>
```

And I would like to have access to `hidePanel` property in the jsp file of `generic layout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

Retrieve page properties from a jsp:

```
<%
  PageResult pageResult = (PageResult) request.getAttribute("PAGE");
  boolean hidePanel = Boolean.valueOf(pageResult.getProperty("hidePanel")));
%>
```

Comment: Can I ask if you know how to go about this within the "controller" that is backing this portlet/page request?